# django exclude self from queryset for validation

Tags: django, validation, django-queryset

I am working with my own clean method to see if some other table already had a field with the same string.
This all goes fine as long as i am creating one, but when i try to edit it, it find "itself" and gives back the error.
Now am i wondering how can i exclude the instance itself in my clean method

```
def clean_name(self):
    raw_data = self.cleaned_data['name']
    data = raw_data.title()

    if Country.objects.filter(name=data).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(("There is already a country with the name: %s") % data)
    if Province.objects.filter(name=data).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(("There is already a province with the name: %s") % data)
    if Region.objects.filter(name=data).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(("There is already a region with the name: %s") % data) 
    return data
```

i know there is a .exclude()  but that needs a variable to be passed along with it, not sure how i could get that along with my clean method

Comment: Hey cannot understand why you are validating 3 different model classes rather than just the one where an entity with the same `name` would conflict. Usually you exclude by the ID of the existing entity, but in this case which entity are we talking about? Is it `Country`, `Province` or `Region`?

Comment: It does seem like an odd requirement, but it could be perfectly valid in the context of the whole application, which we know nothing about.

Comment: I dont want the name of country/province/region to be the same   matter of style, and all 3 are different tables. not sure how else to do it then like this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your `clean_name` method is on a ModelForm, you can access the associated model instance at `self.instance`. Second, a simple way to tell if a model instance is newly created, or already existing in the database, is to check the value of its primary key. If the primary key is `None`, the model is newly created.

So, your validation logic could look something like this:

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name'].title()
    qs = Country.objects.filter(name=name)
    if self.instance.pk is not None:
        qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    if qs.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("There is already a country with name: %s" % name)
```

I've only shown one query set for clarity. I'd probably create a tuple containing all three querysets, and iterate over them. The code for adding the exclude clause, and the call to `exists()` could all be handled inside the loop, and therefore only needs to be written once (DRY).