# Form validation on insert vs. update

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make one form for both inserting and updating data. I have read these:

- [Model validation on update in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966330/model-validation-on-update-in-django?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [django exclude self from queryset for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564856/django-exclude-self-from-queryset-for-validation)

In my project, however, I am not using ModelForm.

forms.py:

This is the form the user sees when registering his/her username and first_name. It is also the form an existing user sees when trying to change his/her username and/or first_name.

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class SettingsForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    # ... and many more form fields

    def clean_slug(self):
        """Make sure that the username entered by the user will be unique in the database"""

        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            product = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Good, there is no one using this username
            pass 
        else:
            # There is alreaady a user with this username
            raise forms.ValidationError('This username has been used. Try another.')

        return username
```

The form cleaning works as intended for inserting data. However, when updating data, it complains that the username has been used (naturally, since the username already exists in the  database).

How do I update the data without raising ValidationError when using a Form (and without using ModelForm)?

(The reasons for not using ModelForm in this case are: we may stop using the the orm, SettingsForm may contain a mix of fields from different models, some fields may be repeated hundreds of times in the form that is displayed to the user, we also need custom fields not tied to any model, ... and other scenarios that make using ModelForm quite challenging (impossible?). The purpose of this question is to find out if there are ways of achieving the desired result without using ModelForm.)

Comment: Do you want the form to allow changing the username of an existing user?

Comment: @RomanB. Yes. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: You can customize ModelForms pretty well. Have a look at my blog post: https://colinkingswood.github.io/Model-Form-Customisation/

Comment: @wobbily_col It's just that I've always had trouble using ModelForm to do what I imagine. At some point I started to have inline formsets, model formsets and all sorts of factories. It's overwhelming for a beginner, really. I'll continue to learn more about it.

Comment: True if you aren't experienced there can be a lot to learn.

Comment: There is always more to learn. I'm building some functionality (will release as an app eventually) that lets you attach "questions and answers" to any model in your project. The form wrangling involved with that takes wobbily_col's blog post to the next degree. Nothing quite like the satisfaction that results from finally really understanding something that was initially overwhelming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ValidationError is obviously because you're instantiating the SettingsForm when the username already exists, as you've already stated.

So if you want to add a form that can do double-duty, I would add an `__init__` to SettingsForm that takes an `is_update` and saves it as a member variable, like so...

```python
def __init__(self, is_update=False, **kwargs):
    self.is_update = is_update
    return super(SettingsForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

then modify your `clean_slug()` to be:

```python
def clean_slug(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    try:
        product = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # Good, there is no one using this username
        pass 
    else:
        if not self.is_update: # for 'create' usage
            # There is already a user with this username
            raise forms.ValidationError('This username has been used. Try another.')
        else: # for 'update' usage
            pass
    return username
```

Comment: Thank you! So in views.py, I do `forms=SettingsForm(is_update=True)` to update? Would appreciate an example of the use of the form in your answer. Beginner here.

Comment: Sure, basically in your create view you will instantiate the form with `is_update=False`, and in the update with True. If you want it written out, can you put your existing view code where you instantiate the forms into the question and I'll edit that. (Otherwise I can't tell if you're using class-based or function-based views, etc.)

Comment: There's one little problem with the solution. What if for an existing user the new username will be the same as a username of another existing user? It won't raise an error and it should. You need to check if the username is the same as the username of the user that is being updated. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Agreed. Roman's is a better solution. I missed thinking through that edge case, and the idea of passing in the existing User is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You have three cases:

1. The user is new
2. The user exists and doesn't change his/her username
3. The user exists and changes his/her username

You need to check if the username already exists only in the first two cases.

If it's an existing user you should pass the User instance to the form so you can use it in the clean_slug function, let's say in self.user variable.

Then you could just add two lines in the clean_slug function and it should work as you wish:

```
 def clean_slug(self):
    """Make sure that the username entered by the user will be unique in the database"""

    username = self.cleaned_data['username']

    # If the user exists and the username has not been changed, 
    # just return the username
    if self.user and self.user.username == username:
        return username

    try:
        product = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # Good, there is no one using this username
        pass 
    else:
        # There is alreaady a user with this username
        raise forms.ValidationError('This username has been used. Try another.')

    return username
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want your form to do two different things depending if it is a create or an update.

So either have two forms with a different clean_slug method or pass in an argument telling the form if it is an update or a create (there is another answer from neomanic showing this way).

Personally I think the easiest way would be to subclass your form and change the clean slug method. The use the new form for updates and your original form for creates.

```
class UpdateSettingsForm(settingsForm):

    def clean_slug(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        return username
```

Comment: In both cases (whether it's about creating or updating) you need to check if the username already exists, because the user may change it. I think it can be easily handled using only one class.