# Validation Exclude Self From QuerySet

Tags: python, django, validation, model

Originally I had this in my `models.py`

```
def validate_project_name(value,self):
    project_name = Team.objects.filter(Project_name=value)
    if self.pk:
        project_name = project_name.exclude(pk=self.pk)
    if project_name:
        raise ValidationError('This already exists.')


class Team(models.Model):
    Project_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, validators=[validate_project_name])
    Project_number = models.IntegerField()
```

This worked in the sense that it will not allow users to input an already existing `Project_name`. However, now I have incorporated an edit/update functionality. So if a user wants to update his/her own `Team`, it will raise the ValidationError since it exists in the database. So for example, if the User wants to keep the same `Project_name` but update the `Project_number` the error will raise. So I want to exclude `self` from the queryset. I looked at this example:

[django exclude self from queryset for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564856/django-exclude-self-from-queryset-for-validation)

So I simply added the following code within my `class Team`.

```
def clean_name(self):
    project_name = self.cleaned_data['Project_name'].title()
    qs = Team.objects.filter(Project_name=project_name)
    if self.instance.pk is not None:
        qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    if qs.exists():
        raise ValidationError("This already exists")
```

But it is not working as in the validation error is not being raised...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure `clean_name` is even getting called? I was under the impression that models only had a `clean` method, not a method for each individual field (that syntax is used for forms). Try using just `def clean(self):`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: I tried it, now says something: 'Team' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' On this line: project_name = self.cleaned_data['Project_name'].title()

Comment: Read the docs, `cleaned_data` is not valid on model validation. You'll access it like `self.project_name`.